# Identify the PID of process which is transmitting icmp packets

Tags: icmp

I have written a program which will create and transmit the icmp packets over the network.

Now, I want to write a program which will identity the processes (PID) in the system which are transmitting the icmp packets. If I am not wrong, possible output of these program will be PID of the previous program that I have coded and some system processes which are creating and transmitting icmp packets.

NOTE : I have used python for coding, scapy for packets manipulation and PySide for GUI(extra information) I am running this program in Fedora 20 in VMWare.

EDIT : I have written another program which will generate and send the packet to destination. The code is as follows :

```
from scapy.all import *

while True:
    send(IP(dst = '192.168.0.101')/ICMP()/'This is a message')
```

I run this program through terminal and using "ps -e" i found the pid is 2046.
When i run "lsof -p 2046", it gives me following output.

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
python  2263 root  cwd    DIR  253,1      4096  393217 /root
python  2263 root  rtd    DIR  253,1      4096       2 /
python  2263 root  txt    REG  253,1      6412 1312778 /usr/bin/python2.7
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     40536  132769 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/arraymodule.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     76968  132773 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cPickle.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1    141376  132758 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     21576  132804 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/zlibmodule.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     13336  132779 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/fcntlmodule.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     22348  132795 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/selectmodule.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     34952  132768 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_struct.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     21976  132756 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     50736  132784 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertoolsmodule.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     34068  132789 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     29584  132747 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collectionsmodule.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     18708  132800 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/timemodule.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     16936  132774 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cStringIO.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     32804  132767 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     10768  132754 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_functoolsmodule.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1    169076 1313915 /usr/lib/liblzma.so.5.0.99
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1    437616 1314045 /usr/lib/libpcre.so.1.2.1
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1    140980 1324120 /usr/lib/libselinux.so.1
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     14660 1313891 /usr/lib/libkeyutils.so.1.5
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     52740 1311324 /usr/lib/libkrb5support.so.0.1
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     89336 1314317 /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.8
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1    103924 1314111 /usr/lib/libresolv-2.18.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1    217596 1311314 /usr/lib/libk5crypto.so.3.1
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     14816 1313563 /usr/lib/libcom_err.so.2.1
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1    853160 1311323 /usr/lib/libkrb5.so.3.3
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1    296208 1311189 /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1   1875268 1310866 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1    414804 1311008 /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.1e
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     75480  132765 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socketmodule.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     16892  132755 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1 106070928 1320811 /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1   2064488 1313517 /usr/lib/libc-2.18.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1    328148 1313917 /usr/lib/libm-2.18.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     12836 1314239 /usr/lib/libutil-2.18.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     17912 1313596 /usr/lib/libdl-2.18.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1    134608 1314076 /usr/lib/libpthread-2.18.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1   1659436 1314088 /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     14284  132764 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_randommodule.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     23572  132771 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1     30320  132786 /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so
python  2263 root  mem    REG  253,1    150572 1313337 /usr/lib/ld-2.18.so
python  2263 root    0u   CHR  136,1       0t0       4 /dev/pts/1
python  2263 root    1u   CHR  136,1       0t0       4 /dev/pts/1
python  2263 root    2u   CHR  136,1       0t0       4 /dev/pts/1
python  2263 root    5u  sock    0,7       0t0   73120 protocol: UDP
```

Comment: This question is better asked on Stackoverflow. Don't worry, I've already marked it for migration there, so just wait a bit and it will go there.

Comment: I have asked this question there...but no one answered...

Comment: @user3563328 when you run lsof -p 2046 did any of the lines show the st=07 signature?

Comment: any raw lines at all?

Comment: @RоryMcCune: I have attached the complete output of command.
plz check the edited question again.

Comment: Why don't you just write the pid to a file on the disk at a known location, to be read by the other script? That's how I always do it.

Comment: @Abhi: I didn't get it...every time I run a python code for creating and transmitting icmp packet, the pid change. Tell me if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be able to do this with lsof.  if you ping a host then run

```
lsof -p <PID of process doing ping>
```

you can see that it opens a raw connection with a type of st=07 (e.g.)

```
ping    53988 rorym    3u   raw             0t0 137700 00000000:0001->00000000:0000 st=07
```

so having a program that looked for that signature in the output should give you that information.  A crude example could be

```
sudo lsof -n | grep -i st=07
```

so as the potential answer if you run that command it *should* show things that are currently pinging...

Comment: Unfortunately, this requires a knowledge/suspicion of the process originating the request. This wouldn't work if you're just trying to figure out which process is sending those requests amongst the processes running on your system.

Comment: The only a priori method of which I'm aware is by cross-referencing `tcpdump` data with `netstat` output. (any other tools with similar functionality should work)

Comment: @Rory McCune : can you elaborate your answer. I am having hard time understanding it.

Comment: @Rory McCune: Plz check the edited question. I have inserted "lsof -i PID" output. Let me know i am doing anything wrong.

Comment: @Adnan:I dont know about tcpdump but netstat does not give process id for icmp packet.
[link]http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Why_doesnt_the_netstat_command_display_any_information_about_ICMP_connections[link]

Comment: @user3563328 *Sigh*.. please read my comment again. Cross-referencing data means getting data from multiple sources and compiling conclusions based on that knowledge. In this case, you'll get the `tcpdump` (contains traffic information, source ports and protocols), and `netstat` you get source ports and process IDs. You **cross-reference** those two pieces of information and get the process ID that fits your requirements.

Comment: @Adnan ah perhaps I should have been clearer, the point was to prove that that method worked, what I was saying is that you can do lsof -n | grep -i st=07 and you can see what things are sending pings...

Comment: @Adnan:hmmm...that might work. i guess now i have to learn tcpdump and netstat. Anyway, Thank you.

Comment: actually I don't think netstat will work, doesn't show ICMP traffic so you can't use it to correlate the data from tcpdump...

Comment: @RоryMcCune Oho! Now I see what you mean, I'm trying your method and it seems to work. As for netstat, I can see it here in front of me. I get the packet type from tcmpdump and compare the source port to the netstat output. I've just done it for ICMP and other protocols.

Comment: @Adnan how odd when I ran a ping command then ran netstat it didn't seem to show, what switches were ya using?

Comment: @RоryMcCune No no, I don't see the pings in netstat. I'm cross-referencing on source port.